# What are the advantages of using wp_enqueue_script()

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Aside from dependency management, what advantage does `wp_enqueue_script()` have over adding scripts manually?

I currently enqueue 5 scripts and am thinking of minimising HTTP requests by using an inline `<script>` tag instead. For the purposes of this discussion let's forget HTTP/2.

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 4):

How about API? Let's Check this example.

```
$id = 'plugin-id';
$syffix =  ( ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min' );
$script_url = plugins_url( 'js/' .$id . $suffix . '.js', __FILE__ );
$dependencies = array( 'jquery', 'underscore' );
wp_register_script( $id, $script_url, $dependencies, $version, true );

wp_localize_script( $id, 'pluginJSL10nData', array(
    'home' => trailingslashit( get_home_url() ),
    'matches' => __( 'Hello World!', 'plugin-id' ),
) );

wp_enqueue_script( $id );
```

1. `$id` is ID for our script, we can unregister it later (after we declare it, but didn't use) if we change our mind.
2. `$script_url` can point to different scripts
3. `$dependencies` easy to include or exclude dependencies.
4. `$version` we can change the version on script update, and in this case client will be forced to load the new version.
5. `true` or `false` (footer or header), where to include your script.. on your choice.
6. `wp_localize_script` you also van provide additional js variables for your script work, in case if you depend on some specific data. (natively it suppose to be used only for providing localization for your script, but you limited only by your imagination.)
7. `wp_enqueue_script` or not. it depends on you to use the script you register or not.

in other words `wp_register_script`, `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_register_script` provide you api to flexibly use your scripts.

Comment: I think `wp_localize_script()` is a big advantage. I can take advantage of inserting server side data

Comment: It is! BTW, check out how scripts loaded while you in wp-admin (it's directly correlates with your desire to minimize request).

Answer (score 2):

wp_enqueue_script provide lots of advantage in the following cases: 
e.g.

1. We can manage all scripts in one place.
2. We can manage the version of each script.
3. Help to manage dependency of jQuery and other library scripts.
4. We can use wp_register_script for applying on the specific page.
5. wp_enqueue_script also provides an option for where to load script - header or footer.